# Python/Cython/Fortran module - undefined symbol: _gfortran_runtime_error

Tags: python, c, fortran, cython

I want to create a Python module that calls Fortran functions using Cython. I globally works wells, except for the example below where I get a message error from Python when I try to import my module:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Feb  8 2014, 08:16:49) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./m.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_runtime_error
```

The minimum working example is:

**m.pyx**

```
cdef extern from "fortinterface.h":
void f_fortinterface(int* n, float* var, float* resu)

import  numpy as pnp
cimport numpy as cnp

def f(list a):
    cdef cnp.ndarray var  = pnp.array(a,dtype='f',order='F')      #from list to numpy array
    cdef cnp.ndarray resu = pnp.ones(len(a),dtype='f',order='F')

    cdef int n = len(var)
    f_fortinterface(&n, <float*> var.data, <float*> resu.data)

    return resu.tolist()    #back to list from numpy array
```

**fortinterface.f90**

```
module fortinterface

use iso_c_binding
use fortfunction

implicit none

contains

  subroutine f_fortinterface(n,var,resu) bind(c)
  implicit none
  integer(c_int), intent(in)  :: n
  real(c_float),  intent(in)  :: var(n)
  real(c_float),  intent(out) :: resu(n)

  resu(:)  = f_fortfunction(var)

  end subroutine f_fortinterface

end module fortinterface
```

**fortinterface.h**

```
extern void f_fortinterface(int* n, float* var, float* resu);
```

**file fortfunction.f90**

```
module fortfunction

implicit none

contains

  function f_fortfunction(var)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in)   :: var(:)
  real, allocatable  :: f_fortfunction(:)

  allocate(f_fortfunction(size(var)))
  f_fortfunction(:) = var(:)+1.0

  end function f_fortfunction

end module fortfunction
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from numpy import get_include
from os import system

# compile the fortran modules without linking
fortran_mod_comp = 'gfortran fortfunction.f90 -c -o fortfunction.o -fPIC'
print fortran_mod_comp
system(fortran_mod_comp)
shared_obj_comp = 'gfortran fortinterface.f90 -c -o fortinterface.o -fPIC'
print shared_obj_comp
system(shared_obj_comp)

# needed if building with NumPy : this includes the NumPy headers when compiling.
path_includes = [get_include()]

ext_modules =    [Extension('m',                                                      # module name:
                            ['m.pyx'],                                                # source file:
                            extra_link_args=['fortfunction.o', 'fortinterface.o'])]   # other files to link to

setup(name = 'm',
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      include_dirs = path_includes,
      ext_modules  = ext_modules)
```

and I compile everything with

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The error message clearly indicates a problem in the inclusion of libraries (during link edition, I guess). I tried to add several options for gfortran and gcc (-lm, lgfortran, ...) with no success. I am very puzzled because the error comes from the use of the allocatable array

```
f_fortfunction
```

in the file `fortfunction.f90`

Indeed, if I replace the allocatable array with a static array, everything works fine. It is however not an acceptable solution for me because the function may return arrays of varying sizes and I really need its dynamic allocation

Modified (working) **fortfunction.f90**

```
module fortfunction

implicit none

contains

  function f_fortfunction(var)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in)   :: var(:)
  real               :: f_fortfunction(2)

  f_fortfunction(:) = var(:)+1.0

  end function f_fortfunction

end module fortfunction
```

In that case, I get what I want:

```
>>> import m
>>> m.f([1,3])
[2.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: Just a workaround, but can't you allocate the arrays with numpy then pass them to the `f_fortfunction` function? I mean, you are doing that already, why do you need to allocate an array with the same shape in the Fortran function again?

Comment: You are right. I can do that (and I did), writing `f_fortfunction` as a subroutine instead of a function. It works well.
The thing is that I also want the code in `fortfunction.f90` to be directly callable from a fortran main program (in the end, I want to develop some code in a Fortran library that can be called from Python and Fortran with the same syntax, this syntax being to return an array (or list) of values). According to a collegue of mine, I should avoid using Python arrays allocated by Fortran. This is very risky. I may have to change my code architecture to get what I want.

Comment: Yes, allocating array with Numpy (or alternatively in your main Fortran code)  would probably be best. Still the error message is strange. I tried adding `-lgfortranbegin` and `-static-libgfortran` to the link flags, without much success (same error at import with gcc 4.9.2 and cython 0.22). Otherwise you could try using f2py, ctypes or cffi.

Comment: `f2py` of `ctypes` could work, but the problem of using Python arrays allocated from Fortran remains. The cython approach above works well with minimum efforts to get what I want (using 1 kernel function in Fortran, 1 interface to call from fortran program and 1 interface to call from Python through Cython). Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Do not use tag [tag:fortran90] without the tag [tag:fortran]. And use [tag:fortran90] only when necessary to distinguish from other veersions like [tag:fortran95] and others. You are actually using Fortran 2003!

Comment: @rth the `libfortranbegin` is obsolete in GCC 4.9.2, it does nothing. It is being removed completely for GCC 6.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to correct this issue by linking the library for `gfortran` in the `Extension` object in `setup.py`, rather than trying to manually link the library.

#### Modified `setup.py`

Works with the original `fortfunction.f90` and gives the expected result (tested on Python3). Only change is the inclusion of `libraries` in `ext_modules`.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from numpy import get_include
from os import system

# compile the fortran modules without linking
fortran_mod_comp = 'gfortran fortfunction.f90 -c -o fortfunction.o -fPIC'
print fortran_mod_comp
system(fortran_mod_comp)
shared_obj_comp = 'gfortran fortinterface.f90 -c -o fortinterface.o -fPIC'
print shared_obj_comp
system(shared_obj_comp)

# needed if building with NumPy : this includes the NumPy headers when compiling.
path_includes = [get_include()]

ext_modules =    [Extension('m',                                                      # module name:
                            ['m.pyx'],                                                # source file:
                            libraries = ['gfortran'],                                 # need to include gfortran as a library
                            extra_link_args=['fortfunction.o', 'fortinterface.o'])]   # other files to link to

setup(name = 'm',
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      include_dirs = path_includes,
      ext_modules  = ext_modules)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use automatic arrays instead of allocatable arrays in Fortran. Here is an example of `fortfunction.f90` that works,

```
function f_fortfunction(var, n)
implicit none
real, intent(in)   :: var(:)
integer, intent(in)   :: n
real:: f_fortfunction(size(var))

f_fortfunction(:) = var(:)+1.0

end function f_fortfunction
```

Comment: Works very fine! I thought using an automatic array would lead to the same problem as using a allocatable array, but it does not. Thank you very much.